# VHDL - Interfacing with specific ports on a bus

Tags: syntax, vhdl

I have a bus:

```
    A(7 downto 0)
```

and i'm creating an component that interfaces with it on 7, 6 and 0, is there a way for me to create a

```
    std_logic_vector(7,6,0)?
```

simply for the sake of staying consistent with the pins on bus A()?
I'm sure i could do something like:

```
    std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) -- or maybe even
    ASeven, Asix, Azero : in std_logic;
```

and assign the pins accordingly, but it'd be a lot nicer for reference etc(i think) if i could create a vector.

Thanks in Advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Either make a signal x(7 downto 0) and disregard the spare signals (the compiler/synthesizer will do, anyway), or you can use an appropriate assignment in your port map like

`port map(

   myoutport(0) => aZero,

    ...`


or something. In general, use the first variant, as it is more consistent.

Comment: Simple enough, thought there might be some elegant way of doing it. That works though!
P.S. Thanks :)